# Is ggradar able to handle missing values?

Tags: r, visualization

i have a new question:

is ggradar able to handle missing values?

This is my code. Unfortunately in the radardata df there is one variable with a lot of NAs.

```
library(ggradar)

ggradar(radardata, grid.min = 0, grid.max = 5,
        values.radar = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in if (min(plot.data[, -1]) < centre.y) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Within the package description i could not find anything about missing values.
Is there a possibility to handle them or should i use another package?

Comment: Doesn't look like it does, as the error code is showing that under the hood `ggradar` isn't using `na.rm = F` in that `min()` call.

Comment: Thank you! That means also that it isnt possible to add "empty" categories i.e. additional variables where there are no values yet?!